# How to Run Jar on java 7 compiled in java 8 or higher version

Tags: java, java-8, jar, java-7

I have created a windows application using java 8 . But my client is using java 7 on his machine and not able to upgrade java on the machine.

So when i run jar on java7 compiled in java 8 it gives error so can i convert jar 
   compatible to lower version java

Comment: compile your jar with java 7

Comment: i dont have java7 and while using java8 can i install java 7 also

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple java version installed.

Comment: Compile for java 7. Use a flag for javac

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change a compiled jar's Java version. You have 2 option in hand.

> 1. Compile the Source code using Java-7.
> 2. Compile source code using Java-8 but using the following command when target vm version is java-7.

```
javac "Your java classes" -source 1.8 -target 1.7
```

Comment: It's actually quite doable to change the class file format version after the fact (unless you have used new Java 8 API or a language feature like lambdas).

Comment: What if one does not use any jdk8 features, compile 1.8 and target 1.8. Will it work?

Answer (score 5):

Java 7 is forward compatible with Java 8. Java 8 can be compiled so that it runs on a Java 7 VM (with -source 7 -target 7), but you can’t use any of the newer APIs.
Just Compile with JAVA 7 and you would be good to go just make sure you are not using new features of java 8 like lamda

Comment: What if one does not use any jdk8 features, compile 1.8 and target 1.8. Will it work?

Comment: @Gaurav sure it will work, I dont see problem.. do you mean you are writting code like you are writting java 7 but compailing to java 8? I think it will work..! not 100% sure but think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to compile with Java 7. You can run multiple Java version and choose which version should be used to compile: [Multiple Java versions running concurrently under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271609/multiple-java-versions-running-concurrently-under-windows)

Comment: No, you can build a Java 7 binary with javac of Java 8. See target flag of javac: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851611/javac-source-and-target-options-usage

Comment: It looks you are right, I did not know that