# Cannot change Java source level to 1.7 in Eclipse with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I tried using a multi-catch statement in my Java Project. It doesn't give any errors in the IDE, but when I do `Run As->Maven Install` I get the following error (removed personal file paths as those are not relevant I think):

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project: Compilation failure
MyClass.java:[137,39] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
```

As per the other answers on this site, I tried changing the Java version in my project properties. However, everything was already set to Java 1.7. My **Java Build Path**

[image: java build path]

My **Java Compiler** settings:

[image: java compiler settings]

What should I change to be able to use Java 1.7 properly?

Comment: Have you updated the source versions etc in the `pom.xml` file?

Comment: @Gavin I have now and everything works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay somehow I missed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750563/maven-doesnt-use-java-7?rq=1) before. I didn't come up at all when googling about the exact error strangely enough.
To fix it I simply had to add:

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

</properties>
```

to my project's pom.xml as maven was not using the java version from my eclipse project settings.